# Recursion java - differently for loop does not understand how to work

Tags: java, recursion

I understand the principle of recursion and code but do not understand the loop for,Why variables are in the same line, we can explain how the loop works?

this line:

```
 for (int i = digit, j = 1; i >= 1; i--, j++)
```

The code:

```
public static boolean hasSubSeries(int[] arr, int digit) {
    return hasSubSeriesHelper(arr, arr.length, digit);
}

public static boolean hasSubSeriesHelper(int[] arr, int size, int digit) {
    if (size == 0)
        return false;

    for (int i = digit, j = 1; i >= 1; i--, j++) {
        if (arr[size - j] != i)
            return hasSubSeriesHelper(arr, size - 1, digit);
    }

    return true;
 }
```

thank's

Comment: for( initialization; stop if false; moving steps). For your case, initially, i is digit, j is 1. stop until i is 0 or smaller. for every step, i--, j++

Answer (score 1):

The structure of the **for** loop is as follows:

```
for( starting conditions; verification at each loop; action at end of loop)
```

In your specific case:

```
for (int i = digit, j = 1; i >= 1; i--, j++)
```

- **Starting conditions:**

  - A variable `i` which is equal to the value contained in the variable `digits` that is given at the start of the function `hasSubSeriesHelper(int[] arr, int size, int digit)`.
  - A variable `j` which starts at `1`.
- **Verification at each loop:**

  - Once each loop is completed we will check this, if it is True, we keep on looping, if not we exit the loop.
  - We check to see if `i` declared at the start is greater than or equal to 1, if it is we keep on looping, if not we stop.
- **Action at end of loop:**

  - We do two actions `i--` which decreases the value of `i` by `1` and `j++` which increases the value of `j` by `1`.

To summarise you could translate it to a `while` loop if you prefer:

```
int i = digit; 
int j = 1;
while ( i >= 1 ) {
    // the code inside the for loop goes here
    i--;
    j++;
}
```

Note that the actions at the end happen inside the loop whilst the starting condditions go before the loop.

That should also clarify why you can have various declarations in the same line as long as they are of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

You have three parts in a `for` loop

- N°1 : Initialization of variable(s)
- N°2 : Boolean expression evaluated to continue/stop looping
- N°3 : Changes operated on variables

---

### 1

You may have multiple initialization in the first part, as long as the type stay the same, the following is entirely possible :

We declare and instantiate three variables within the first part of our `for` declaration.

```
for(int i = 2, j = 2*i, k = 4*j ; i < 3 ; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + j + " " + k); // 2 4 16
}
```